# Approximating rational generating functions

Tags: generating-functions, tag-removed, rational-functions, approximation-theory

Suppose we have a initial segment $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ (for reasonably large $N$) of a sequence of natural numbers $(x_i)$. We have reason to believe the generating function $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_iX^i$ is rational. Are there any methods one could use to guess/approximate this generating function as a quotient of polynomials $P(X)/Q(X)$ with small degrees (relative to $N$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Padé approximation.  There are several computer packages that can do that, in particular GFUN (Salvy and Zimmermann) for maple, Guess (Kauers) for mathematica, in FriCAS it's built-in (the function is called guessPade).  You can access the latter also from sage, although very likely there is something built-in too.